# Select and drag text on Mac OS X 10.6 doesn't allow me to drag

Tags: drag-and-drop, osx-snow-leopard, text-editor, textselection

I have just been enlightened on what I previously thought was a short-coming of the whole Mac OS X platform - that like Windows, a user may select a block of text and drag it. This is particularly useful in developing.

However, the reason I thought it wasn't an available option was because it has never worked for me. No programs allow for select and drag, and I've gone through several online tutorials and forums to see if anybody else has the same issue. None of my work-mates can figure it out.

Why would my whole system dis-allow text dragging? Now that I know it's possible, it's driving me crazy not being able to do it.

I've gone through the System Preferences and the Mouse panel has no specific drag option. Trackpad has a single-finger drag option, but that's not allowing dragging, even with the trackpad.

I'm on a Macbook Pro, from around 2008. I'm using an external mouse and running OS 10.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably be on apple.stackexchange.com instead of here, but be that as it may... the trick is that you need to hold the mouse down for a fraction of a second, until the mouse cursor changes from an insertion point to an arrow, and then you can drag.

Comment: Okay, I'll try apple.stackexchange.com. The cursor never changes, no matter how long I hold the mouse button for.